# Trouble Aligning Buttons Within a div

Tags: css, button, alignment

I'm making a simple calculator page but I'm having a lot of trouble aligning the buttons the way I would like. I have all of my buttons inside of a div which is already the width I want each row of buttons to be. My problem is that no matter how I try to do the margins or the buttons either have extra room on the right side and they don't line up with the right side of the viewport or they are too big and they overflow onto the next line. I'm sure there is a simple solution to this but I'm too much of a beginner to see it. :(

Currently my CSS for the button container and buttons is as follows:

```
#buttons {
  width:525px;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

button {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/ChrFimbel/pen/rYLNWr).

Comment: Probably this might help? https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/83029/74659

Answer (score 0):

Try *width: 33%* on the buttons. It tells the browser to use (roughly) 1/3rd if the available space for each button.

Answer (score 0):

[Flex box is worth learning](https://duckduckgo.com/html?q=flexbox&t=lmddgtfy&kae=-1).

Changes are noted with `/**/` in the CSS.

Full example, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LOZEPp

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #141414;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  display: flex; /**/
  justify-content: center; /**/
  padding: 0; /**/
  margin: 0; /**/
}


#calc-main {
  background-color: #607466;
  width: 550px; /**/
  height: 700px; /**/
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: flex; /**/
  flex-direction: column; /**/
  justify-content: space-around; /**/
}

#calc-brand {
  flex: 1; /**/
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0; /**/
  margin: 10px; /**/
}

#calc-viewport {
  flex: 1; /**/
  margin: 10px; /**/
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #D4D2A5;
  padding: 0.25em; /**/
  text-align: right;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#buttons {
  margin: 10px; /**/
  flex: 16; /**/
  background: orange; /**/
  display: flex; /**/
  flex-direction: column; /**/
  align-items: center; /**/
  padding: 5px; /**/
}

.button-row { /**/
  flex: 1; /* important */
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%; /**/
  margin: 5px; /**/
  display: flex; /**/
  flex-direction: row; /**/
  justify-content: space-between; /**/
}

button {
  flex: 1; /* important */
  max-width: 110px; /**/
  max-height: 110px; /**/
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px; /**/
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
  <div id='calc-main'>
    <h1 id='calc-brand'>JAVASCRIPT CALCULATOR</h1>
    <div id='calc-viewport'>
      <p id='main-output'>0</p>
      <p id='secondary-output'>0</p>
    </div>
      <div id=buttons>
        <div class="button-row">
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>AC</button>
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>CE</button>
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>CE</button>
          <button type='button'>÷</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-row">
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>AC</button>
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>CE</button>
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>CE</button>
          <button type='button'>÷</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-row">
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>AC</button>
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>CE</button>
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>CE</button>
          <button type='button'>÷</button>
        </div>
        <div class="button-row">
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>AC</button>
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>CE</button>
          <button type='button' class='button-danger'>CE</button>
          <button type='button'>÷</button>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #607466;
}

.result {
    margin:10px 20px;
}

input {
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

span {
    background: #AAA;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 10px 10px;
    line-height: 60px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid;
}

span:hover {
    background-color: #AAA;
}

.result ~ p {
    padding-left: 10px;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <p class="result"><input type="text" name="result"></p>
    <p><span>AC</span><span>CE</span><span>/</span><span>*</span></p>
    <p><span>7</span><span>8</span><span>9</span><span>-</span></p>
    <p><span>4</span><span>5</span><span>6</span><span>+</span></p>
    <p><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>=</span></p>
    <p><span>0</span><span>.</span><span>Invisible</span></p>
    <br style="clear: both">
</div>
```